# Outlook MSG to MimeMessage in Java

Tags: java, outlook, msg, eml, mime-message

Is there any way (open source way) to convert Outlook .msg to MimeMessage so that someone can work with msg files in Java?

There is a library named MsgParser developed for working with .msg files but this library does not give an option to convert .msg to MimeMessage, it has its own Message class. I really need to convert the msg to MimeMessage.

If there is no way to do it in Java, is there any open-source tool for linux which makes conversion from command line?

Comment: None that I know of - but with MsgParser already there it should be possible to create a "more or less equal" mime message. Depending on how much of the MIME headers is preserved in .msg

Comment: http://www.independentsoft.de/jmsg/tutorial/convertmsgtomime.html

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Was the link provided above enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to convert outlooks msg files to eml.  I picked up the code and library from: https://github.com/ctabin/jotlmsg
Note that jotlmsg requires apache POI + dependencies and Javax.mail

```
    package MsgToMime;
    import ch.astorm.jotlmsg.OutlookMessage;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    public class MsgToMime {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable{

            OutlookMessage message0 = new OutlookMessage(new File("myMessage.msg"));
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = message0.toMimeMessage();
            mimeMessage.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("myMessage.eml")));   

        }

    }
```